# Where can I find code that allows me to calculate Z1 and Z2 from an ECDSA signature?

Tags: private-key, ecdsa, recover-private-key

By following [Recovering Bitcoin private keys using weak signatures from the blockchain](http://www.nilsschneider.net/2013/01/28/recovering-bitcoin-private-keys.html), I am able to do other calculations, but I have no idea how to calculate `Z1` or `Z2`. There was a public code available by [Sean Bradley](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/32546/2306):

http://2coin.org/tx.asmx?op=GetTXExtended

But it does not seems to work now. Is there some other public code to calculate `Z1` and `Z2` in any language. I can convert it to the language of my preference. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you maybe describe what you want this for?  I don't want to unintentionally help someone steal other people's bitcoins.

Comment: @DavidA.Harding I am a security researcher and want to replicate this attack. All the vulnerable addresses are already on internet and empty. And vulnerable applications are already fixed. I just want to replicate this nothing else.

Comment: I provided an answer.  However, the attack Nils's describes is just a basic re-used `k` value attack.  If you really want to replicate it, you'll find it much simpler jettisoning Bitcoin's baggage and doing the math for your own arbitrary hashed data.  Even Wikipedia has [instructions for doing this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA#Signature_generation_algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

According to Nils's post, the `z` values are the hashes that get signed in the ECDSA formula.  Background on what data goes into these hashes can be found on the [OP_CHECKSIG wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG) and Krzysztof Okupski's excellent [developer reference PDF](https://github.com/minium/Bitcoin-Spec).

Bitcoin Core's code for generating the hashes is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/sign.cpp#L94).  Any other Bitcoin application that signs transactions (or verifies signatures) must have a compatible function (at least for the default SIGHASH_ALL), so you should be able to find an implementation in pretty much any popular programming language.

Answer (score 0):

paste your transaction into this page
https://2xoin.com/getRSZfromRawTX/

it will give you all the R,S and Z if it was able to decode the TX.

for example,
`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`

will output

```
[
  {
    "sigR": "d47ce4c025c35ec440bc81d99834a624875161a26bf56ef7fdc0f5d52f843ad1",
    "sigS": "44e1ff2dfd8102cf7a47c21d5c9fd5701610d04953c6836596b4fe9dd2f53e3e",
    "sigZ": "c0e2d0a89a348de88fda08211c70d1d7e52ccef2eb9459911bf977d587784c6e",
    "pubKey": "04dbd0c61532279cf72981c3584fc32216e0127699635c2789f549e0730c059b81ae133016a69c21e23f1859a95f06d52b7bf149a8f2fe4e8535c8a829b449c5ff",
    "N": 0
  },
  {
    "sigR": "d47ce4c025c35ec440bc81d99834a624875161a26bf56ef7fdc0f5d52f843ad1",
    "sigS": "9a5f1c75e461d7ceb1cf3cab9013eb2dc85b6d0da8c3c6e27e3a5a5b3faa5bab",
    "sigZ": "17b0f41c8c337ac1e18c98759e83a8cccbc368dd9d89e5f03cb633c265fd0ddc",
    "pubKey": "04dbd0c61532279cf72981c3584fc32216e0127699635c2789f549e0730c059b81ae133016a69c21e23f1859a95f06d52b7bf149a8f2fe4e8535c8a829b449c5ff",
    "N": 1
  }
]
`
```