# Same identical R value of all transaction not provide corresponding privatekey

Tags: transactions, private-key, signature, ecdsa

[ECDSA Signature and the “z” value](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25814/ecdsa-signature-and-the-z-value)

from above link learn calculation of z value and to get private key

https://blockchain.info/tx/9ec4bc49e828d924af1d1029cacf709431abbde46d59554b62bc270e3b29c4b1

transaction you get

R = d47ce4c025c35ec440bc81d99834a624875161a26bf56ef7fdc0f5d52f843ad1

S1 = 44e1ff2dfd8102cf7a47c21d5c9fd5701610d04953c6836596b4fe9dd2f53e3e

S2 = 9a5f1c75e461d7ceb1cf3cab9013eb2dc85b6d0da8c3c6e27e3a5a5b3faa5bab

Z1 = c0e2d0a89a348de88fda08211c70d1d7e52ccef2eb9459911bf977d587784c6e

Z2 = 17b0f41c8c337ac1e18c98759e83a8cccbc368dd9d89e5f03cb633c265fd0ddc

z = 7a1a7e52797fc8caaa435d2a4dace39158504bf204fbe19f14dbb427faee50ae

private key = c477f9f65c22cce20657faa5b2d1d8122336f851a508a1ed04e479c34985bf96

**but the other transaction not providing corresponding private key**

**with same identical 
R value = d47ce4c025c35ec440bc81d99834a624875161a26bf56ef7fdc0f5d52f843ad1**

https://blockchain.info/tx/47106ff70bf779efc32230f5ca956d0fc563f35a3c4395d1977fc38995327fe1

https://blockchain.info/tx/00b4dea9266283d93f35240f34b871b55e59c3d4a7705aa08d5745af398d9046

https://blockchain.info/tx/d6f071e082ebb8c7c7721a9019d7478489e3fd423cae6acabdbd2ffd28f5c300

https://blockchain.info/tx/83415dded4757181c6e1c55104e2742a6f8cff05a9a46fbf029ae47b0054d511

https://blockchain.info/tx/2bd15366f5bcc2046c480db4d6ad82450893f2a3370935ddee753325f1a7c6cc

https://blockchain.info/tx/e96feca9744b95533a5a3f657c346d7772a5004a76f4bc8de810b7ad015f6440

https://blockchain.info/tx/5a994f485039ebd83a0ed22cae943f0c792d85d218884f4cd80bd7cccdd75aae

Comment: Keep in mind that the signs of the S values might have been flipped and you will need to try unflipping them.  My answer on another post has an explanation and example code for doing this: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35848/recovering-private-key-when-someone-uses-the-same-k-twice-in-ecdsa-signatures/35850#35850

Comment: Hi again, Prabu. I'm not sure I understand. When I try all of those transactions, I always find the same c477f9... private key (without even needing David Grayson's trick to compensate for tx malleability). Could you be more specific?

Comment: Hi Christopher Gurnee, your get same private key all transaction can you please explain two of the transaction getting same value in detail step by step  like (http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25814/ecdsa-signature-and-the-z-value) Willem Hengeveld

Comment: I used the Python code described in [this answer](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37760/converting-ruby-script-into-python-recovering-private-key-when-someone-uses-th/37762#37762) and the modified `tx` utility I mentioned in [this comment](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37761/any-bitcoin-transaction-to-get-s1-and-z1-and-r-value-script-need#comment-44194). Let me know if you'd still like an answer here....

Comment: Christopher Gurnee, i try many time other transaction i m not getting same private key , and your mention some Python code there is no r s z getting script thank your help