# I need help with regaining acces back go my adress

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions

can someone points to wsite which can calculate the nonce of a checksig, if needed i have files and proofs that im doing it for my own sake and i dont need to harm another person adress, i just want to have acces to mine once more, and be careful after i do. Or perse if i do. 2nd PS, before someone else do.

i read somewhere that if 2 nonces are the same, you can find a private key and about the adress, simply its personal, but let's say i wasn't on public surface and left an adress with some coins inside which can help me

Comment: (1) by checksig do you mean [OP_CHECKSIG](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG) or something else? (2) Can you explain *"regaining acces back go my adress"* in more detail?

Comment: Yes, i read somewhere that if 2 nonces are the same, you can find a private key and about the adress, simply its personal, but let's say i wasn't on public surface and left an adress with some coins inside which can help me

Comment: Does this help: [How to derive the Private key when the two the nonces are k and k*2](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/110956/13866)

Comment: I saw this, in fact isnt that a somewhat of scam? I have troubles where and how to calculate all this because siggs are big values and all I found in the web is website which i think only show a sample, but dont really shows my privkey

Comment: The referenced question and its answers don't describe a scam (nor are they a scam). This is because good software chooses nonces randomly each time one is used. This means that the vulnerability should not arise if you use good software. As I said before, I would never never never type a private key into a website.

Comment: I understand, but in case like that i have to calculate it manually?  Or i have to find a bad site which will give me the right answer and move on fast?

Comment: I would write a short program in one of my favourite languages to perform the calculations described. Many programming languages have good ECDSA libraries and support for large numbers (bigInt etc). There might be other approaches available for non-programmers but they all have their own risks. Maybe there's a trustworthy javascript program that can be downloaded and run offline.  --- However, I have a strong feeling you may be choosing the wrong way to solve whatever your fundamental problem is (recovering a lost wallet?)

Comment: But at least the sample in the software must be right? I will name it asecurity.com,i can use their sample atleast to derive it? Can you suggest also something that's more user friendly, let's say exactly for person who really have no experience (me). Thank you by the way

Comment: If you don't have the private key corresponding to the address the coins were sent to, the coins are not yours, and nobody will help you be able to get access to them. The concern about duplicated nonces only applies in case broken software was used to spend. Proper wallet software does not let anyone but the owner access the coins.

Comment: @PieterWuille: I think that last comment of yours would be a whole answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the private key corresponding to the address the coins were sent to, the coins are not yours, and nobody can help you get access to them.

While it is true that if two signatures exist spending coins from the same key with the same nonce, one can compute the private key from those signatures. However, no sane wallet software will ever repeat nonces, so in order to use this mechanism, the coins must already be held by broken software.

> can someone points to wsite which can calculate the nonce of a checksig

No such website or software exists. The nonce used for a signature is secret, and only known to the signer. If you knew their nonce, you could compute the private key already.

> if needed i have files and proofs that im doing it for my own sake and i dont need to harm another person adress

That's irrelevant, nobody can help you get access to coins you don't have the private key for.

> i just want to have acces to mine once more

I'm sure you do, but I hope you realize that if this were possible at all, Bitcoin would be utterly broken. The whole point is not needing to trust anyone not to steal your coins.