# i find r s z from tow transaction but the r value is not same

Tags: private-key, blockchain.info, public-key, ecdsa

i need your help plase
i find r s z from tow transaction but the r value is not same

from this wallet 1XCPdWb6kk7PGfvbdRbRuNh51aPc4vqC7

this is information
tx 1 b152df9fc1087066cc12ec69c441f35559d794267209fd03f6d3f1d257b69549

raw tx : 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

THE R1  700d06f0d24f18e89acaf250b137b25066b4abea1f3cab58ba48b3dac7e3ede7
THE S1  32236390aa15f60370236a9b88a5fbcc95aca95bbc7c32be2e781daf5ed1cd16
THE Z1  b28f435e053ba045130a39562570bb7fcb7100d6501cb1571ee7bea979ea6377
THE PUBKEY : 0433e05b29670f19cbc499f207f11abe1c69f77f00d5cbb9dbec5b5fe7527e2f41fa1e90f10a05e9c0a34d255988082e190c9ee7ea05f62297d4f76d9b61d7561b')

tx 2 4fa22a2149dd320655425ad7a88b6f6aad87afe10bcf7117c2499b1d5af9529c

raw tx 2 : 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

('THE R2 e13d5d80bab1b5734684334c652cdaa53bd63003b3fb5044e7cfabb78e3e6621')
('THE S2 07f8c435382190f1b7d3f0318924e886360ff2b4a7a565fb36d2ed6b936b3e3e')
('THE Z2 1e8faed746b6bcfbc42d8c2c75b58e1ba2f9059089be669bbb9365b84937e89c')
('THE PUBKey 0433e05b29670f19cbc499f207f11abe1c69f77f00d5cbb9dbec5b5fe7527e2f41fa1e90f10a05e9c0a34d255988082e190c9ee7ea05f62297d4f76d9b61d7561b')

this is the wallet
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1XCPdWb6kk7PGfvbdRbRuNh51aPc4vqC7

And I'm going to send some money to someone who will help me. Please, all I want is to get the private key for this wallet.
I searched again and again and did not find any solution or I did not understand the methods well Please my brothers I want help urgently
I found these variables R S Z, but the variable R is different in financial transactions. Is there a way to extract the private key via R different
I want a full explanation and if you can attach me the last result which is the private key in the messages

Help me even by a tool to find the private key via two variables of the value R

Comment: You can't. Otherwise Bitcoin, and ECDSA in general, would be broken.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/25814/5406

Answer (score 2):

A private key is retrievable if two different messages are signed using *the same* `r` value and the same private key. Two signatures using different values for `r` are insufficient to recover a private key.

You are asking for help to break one of the core cryptographic assumptions that make Bitcoin work. If what you are trying to do were possible, ECDSA would be considered broken and any form of address-reuse would leak private keys. To the best of my knowledge, neither of these two are currently the case.